# My system is not connecting to development server 127.0.0.1:8000 for a django project

Tags: python, django, localhost

I am using Windows 8.1. When I run a command to start the django server using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it runs fine. But when I open `127.0.0.1:8000` in the browser it says:

```
This site can't be reached.
127.0.0.1 took too long to respond.
```

I have already tried to change the port number by using

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

but still it doesn't run.

Please help me solving this issue.

Comment: Are there any errors in the command window?

Comment: no there are no errors in cmd.It is showing starting development server at 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: `localhost:8000` do the same? If django runs fine then it won't be a problem with django..

Comment: try set any ip `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`

Comment: what does the command window say exactly after you `runserver`?

Comment: @Cameron It displays that development server started at 127.0.0.1:8000